# Set a Solr field to be indexed

Tags: solr, indexing, record

I have a solr instance with some "stored" fields, due to a mistake one field was not set to indexed="true" and now I'd like to activate index for that field.

Do I have to reindex the whole records by updating that field or there's something better to be done?

Comment: yes, you have to. No other option.

Comment: if you want to search on previous data, then u need to re-index the data after restart the server. Otherwise, just restart the server and you will be able to search on new data which will be index.

Answer (score 0):

Try and restart your Solr server and check but I am almost certain that if you want to use thata data you will need to re-index!

Comment: Yes, before asking I already tried to restart and try to search on that field, but nothing happened so I really suppose there's no other option.